# Does __init__.py create a namespace, or does it take on the pkg-namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
foopkg
  |- __init__.py 
  |- bar.py
  |- baz.py 


__init__.py 
  from bar import *
  from baz import *
  from suds.client import Client as client


bar.py
class Croak:
  import foopkg
  foopkg.client()
```

python3.2>> import foopkg

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'

Why??

Comment: it's not a verbatim paste, basically i'm trying to do do some initialization in __init__ and use those results everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing bar before client. So, at the moment foopkg.client() gets executed foopkg has no client yet.

Comment: Circular import are possible, but tricky and easy to get wrong, as this illustrates.